# Flutter in Android Studio not visible in Project pane

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I don't know what i clicked but now my flutter project is not visible in project pane on android studio.

Here is how it looks now:

[image]

Notice there is no Flutter project view.

Below is how it normally is:

[image]

Not sure what settings i made wrong.

Comment: Do you have Flutter Plugin installed in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The Flutter project view will be in the `lib/` folder

Comment: Look at the side menus. They are not visible on first instance. I know flutter project is is lib folder